# Fuzzy search on tags with FTS / Lucene

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, alfresco

I would like to do the following query in a fts search : *TAG:(turte~0.5)*
but this is not working. The expected results would be documents tagged with 'turtle'

*TAG:(turte)~0.5* works but this is obviously not the same query and the results are completly off.

Is it possible to add fuzzy on tags ? how / why not ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Fuzzy queries work on every field. When you don't specify the field, you are simply using the default field.

TAG:turte~0.5  should simply work

Comment: It works on my index. Can you open the index with LUKE and try the query? for me (Lucene 3.5) works with TAG:turte~0.5 and does not with TAG:(turte)~0.5 what are the properties of the TAG field? Is it INDEXED? STORED?

Comment: @{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}tagScopeCache et tagScopeSummary are. Should there a be a TAG one then ? I don't know about STORED.